# Show that at least one of these $15$ numbers is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers

> Let $15$ be natural numbers greater than $1$ and less than $1998$ such
> that any two are prime to each other. Show that at least one of these
> $15$ numbers is prime.

**Attempt:**
We will call the 15 first primes, that is, $ \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11,13, ..., 47 \} $, by $ \epsilon_i $.

Suppose the natural $15 $ is composed of say $ a_i $. If we choose primes greater than $47 $, say $p_i $, as a factor of $a_i $, we have to choose one of the $15 $ required primes, because $47 <p $, $ \quad 47 \cdot 47 <p_1 \cdot 47 <p_1 p_2 $

But like $47^2>2000$, then the problem boils down to those $15$ primes.

Note that $\{\epsilon_i^2\}$ is not contained in $\{1,...,1998\}$, as $47^2>2000$. $ \epsilon_i ^ 2 <\epsilon_i \cdot p_i \implies \epsilon_i \cdot p_i $ is not contained in $ \{1, ... 1998 \} $. It is evident that $ \epsilon_i \cdot \epsilon_j $ with $ i \neq j $, or $ \epsilon_i \cdot \epsilon_j \cdot p_i $ also does not make $ 15 $ prime numbers between them, because when choosing $ 2 $, they are missing $14$ and markdown $13$ $\epsilon_i$; when choosing another $2 $, $13 $ and markdown $11$ $ \epsilon_i $, ...
Numbers will be missing from the correct list.

Therefore, by the principle of the house of pigeons, at least one is a cousin

I would like to know if my resolution is correct. And if possible a faster or more elegant solution than my attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is basically correct, although your expression is sometimes a bit hard to understand (perhaps due to English being a foreign language to you?).

For a shorter (but essentially equivalent) solution, let $x_1, \dots, x_{15}$ be $15$ integers in the interval $(1, 1998)$ such that none of them is prime.

For each $i$, let $p_i$ be the smallest prime factor of $x_i$. We have $p_i < \sqrt {1998} < 47$, thus each $p_i$ is among the first $14$ prime numbers.

Therefore pigeon-hole principal tells us that there exist $i \neq j$ such that $p_i = p_j$, which implies that $x_i$ and $x_j$ are not coprime.